# Use non-atomic and atomic operations at the same time

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a pool of threads, each thread contains a counter (it is TLS basically).

A master thread is required to update frequently by computing the sum of all thread-local counters.

Most of the time, each thread increments its own counter, so no synchronization is needed.

But at the time the master thread is updating, I of course need some kind of synchronization.

I came up with MSVS intrinsics (`_InterlockedXXX` functions), and it showed great performance (~ 0.8 s on my test)
However, it limits my code to MSVC compilers and X86/AMD64 platforms, but is there a C++-portable way to do it ?

- I tried changing the int type to `std::atomic<int>` for the counter, using `std::memory_order_relaxed` for the incrementations but this solution is very slow ! (~ 4s)
- When using the base member `std::atomic<T>::_My_val`, the value is accessed non-atomically as I would like to, but it is not portable as well so the problem is the same...
- Using a single `std::atomic<int>` shared by all threads is even slower, due to high contention (~ 10 s)

Do you have some ideas? Perhaps should I use a library (boost)? Or write my own class?

Comment: so the master counter has to be synched all the time?

Comment: Hello,
No, the master counter is sync-ed only when I decide to.

Comment: so you can have regular integer and atomic integer. the master updates the regular int and only when the data has to be synchronized it stores the regular integer value into the atomic one

Comment: also, did you make sure that you build with all the optimizations on? on debug mode, VC++ compiles stores and loads from atomics to monsterous code. on release mode with optimizations the loads and stores are compiled to single `interlocked***`

Comment: we can't help you without a minimal compete example.

Comment: I have used the Release mode with optimizations for fast code.
Still, your idea of using both std::atomic<T> and T is a very good one that I have not thought about !

@RichardHodges: I'll provide you with a snippet later :)

Thank you !

Comment: How about try specialize std::atomic<int> on MSVC ?

Answer (score 2):

`std::atomic<int>::fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)` is just as fast as `_InterlockedIncrement`.

Visual Studio compiles the former to `lock add $1` (or equivalent) and the latter to `lock inc`, but there is no difference in execution time; on my system (Core i5 @3.30 GHz) each take 5630 ps/op, around 18.5 cycles.

Microbenchmark using [Benchpress](https://github.com/blockchaindev/benchpress):

```
#define BENCHPRESS_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "benchpress/benchpress.hpp"
#include <atomic>
#include <intrin.h>

std::atomic<long> counter;
void f1(std::atomic<long>& counter) { counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); }
void f2(std::atomic<long>& counter) { _InterlockedIncrement((long*)&counter); }
BENCHMARK("fetch_add_1", [](benchpress::context* ctx) {
    auto& c = counter; for (size_t i = 0; i < ctx->num_iterations(); ++i) { f1(c); }
})
BENCHMARK("intrin", [](benchpress::context* ctx) {
    auto& c = counter; for (size_t i = 0; i < ctx->num_iterations(); ++i) { f2(c); }
})
```

Output:

```
fetch_add_1                           200000000        5634 ps/op
intrin                                200000000        5637 ps/op
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this kind of implementation which suits me. However, I can't find a way to code `semi_atomic<T>::Set()`

```
#include <atomic>

template <class T>
class semi_atomic<T> {
    T Val;
    std::atomic<T> AtomicVal;
    semi_atomic<T>() : Val(0), AtomicVal(0) {}
    // Increment has no need for synchronization.
    inline T Increment() {
        return ++Val;
    }
    // Store the non-atomic Value atomically and return it.
    inline T Get() {
        AtomicVal.store(Val, std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
        return AtomicVal.load(std::memory_order::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    // Load _Val into Val, but in an atomic way (?)
    inline void Set(T _Val) {
        _InterlockedExchange((volatile long*)&Val, _Val); // And with C++11 ??
    }
}
```

Thank you and tell me if something is wrong !

Comment: "Increment has no need for synchronization" -- this is a fundamental misunderstanding. If a variable can be read from one thread and written to from another you **must** synchronize **both** accesses. If you don't you have a data race, and consequently undefined behavior. It might work just fine, but it will fail when you're demonstrating your application to your most important customer.

Comment: So formalism aside, pretend for a moment that the hardware that you're running on stores an `int` in two bytes, and increments it one byte at a time. For example, if the value is 255, then the high byte holds 0 and the low byte holds 255. To increment the value, 255 is incremented and rolls over to 0, then the high byte is incremented to 1. If another thread reads this value after the low byte gets incremented and before the high byte gets incremented it will see a value of 0.

Comment: You are right, even my Get() function could yield wrong results if Val is passed in a transient state like you mentionned...

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely right : a `std::atomic<int>` per thread is needed for portability, even if it is somehow slow.

However, it can be (very) optimized in the case of X86 and AMD64 architectures.

Here's what I got, `sInt` being a signed 32- or 64- bit.

```
// Here's the magic
inline sInt MyInt::GetValue() {
    return *(volatile sInt*)&Value;
}

// Interlocked intrinsic is atomic
inline void MyInt::SetValue(sInt _Value) {
#ifdef _M_IX86
    _InterlockedExchange((volatile sInt *)&Value, _Value);
#else
    _InterlockedExchange64((volatile sInt *)&Value, _Value);
#endif
}
```

This code will work in MSVS with a X86 architecture (needed for `GetValue()`)